# Site Redirect, really odd

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, rewrite

I just set up Invision Powerboard on my server (Ubuntu 10.10).  We have the name server pointing to my IP via dns record (outside that hosting).

When you access the url in Safari, everything works. Using any other browser, it will redirect you after login to domain.com/domain.com/...

This seems really weird.

*Details removed to protect security/privacy.*

**Using no .htaccess rewrite**
The one generated by IPB, if I chose to enable it would be this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase .nflspot.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . .nflspot.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, this gives me a 500 error.

I'll jump for joy if this gets answered!

Comment: Show us your rewrite rules -- most likely problem is there. For example this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452464/htaccess-rewrite-problem-in-ie -- he got working in ALL browsers except IE.

Comment: IE sucks...see my edit. :)

Comment: Well ... under closer inspection -- browser requests wrong URL in first place: Firefox `GET /admin.nflspot.com/public/style_css/css_1/ipb_print.css HTTP/1.1`; Safari `GET http:/admin.nflspot.com/public/min/index.php?f=admin/skin_cp/acp.css,admin/skin_cp/acp_content.css,admin/skin_cp/acp_editor.css` -- notice only one slash in protocol part. Safari musb be handling it better than other browsers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your login page, I think you are missing a slash (http:/ rather than http://) after the protocol in your form action. When I send the POST, it gets sent to admin.nflspot.com/admin.nflspot.com.... which 404s.

```
<form action='http:/admin.nflspot.com/admin/index.php?adsess=&amp;app=core&amp;module=login&amp;do=login-complete' method='post'>
```

Comment: Fixed it in the conf file.  Simple, stupid mistake. Thanks for finding the answer that shoulda been obvious to me! :)

Comment: Apologies. Looks like LazyOne found the same thing as I was typing up my answer.

Comment: FYI, I'm jumping for joy.